# Restore contents of /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

Tags: 20.04, xfce, xrdp

I was trying to setup remote access to my Ubuntu machine from Windows and followed the advice here: https://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/

However in the step where I am supposed to edit startwm.sh and include the text for xfce, I mistakenly replaced the whole content of the file. I am not sure if this is the reason but I am no longer able to open many applications. I however managed to open one instance of terminal and I need the contents of the original startwm.sh so I can replace, and hopefully restore the system. Could someone point where I can find that please?

Location of sh file: /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

contents of sh file:

```
    #!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startxfce4
```

Comment: Is this possibly what your looking for: https://fossies.org/linux/xrdp/sesman/startwm.sh

Comment: I am not sure, I tried searching for the source and found mutliple versions of the startwm.sh and I understand they are each specific for a setup. Is there a standard one? I apologize, but this is quite new to me so I am not able to select one myself.

Comment: Please EDIT your question and include the output of `startwm.sh`. Also, where is the location of that file?

Comment: Hi @Idias I have added the information. However I re-installed the Ubuntu because I was just starting and this was just blocking everything.

Comment: As I've understood from your question , you want the default contents of the startwm.sh . So I think the best place to start is to look into the ISO file which you've installed this instance from. The original file should be there.

Comment: Ok, but as I mentioned, I reinstalled the OS. I think your suggestion would have been simpler and faster

Comment: I'm glad your issue is resolved. Please mark @ParsaMousav's answer as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original contents is here :

```
#!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

if test -r /etc/default/locale; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    test -z "${LANG+x}" || export LANG
    test -z "${LANGUAGE+x}" || export LANGUAGE
    test -z "${LC_ADDRESS+x}" || export LC_ADDRESS
    test -z "${LC_ALL+x}" || export LC_ALL
    test -z "${LC_COLLATE+x}" || export LC_COLLATE
    test -z "${LC_CTYPE+x}" || export LC_CTYPE
    test -z "${LC_IDENTIFICATION+x}" || export LC_IDENTIFICATION
    test -z "${LC_MEASUREMENT+x}" || export LC_MEASUREMENT
    test -z "${LC_MESSAGES+x}" || export LC_MESSAGES
    test -z "${LC_MONETARY+x}" || export LC_MONETARY
    test -z "${LC_NAME+x}" || export LC_NAME
    test -z "${LC_NUMERIC+x}" || export LC_NUMERIC
    test -z "${LC_PAPER+x}" || export LC_PAPER
    test -z "${LC_TELEPHONE+x}" || export LC_TELEPHONE
    test -z "${LC_TIME+x}" || export LC_TIME
    test -z "${LOCPATH+x}" || export LOCPATH
fi

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

The best way to get it , is either re-installing the `xrdp` package or if that's not possible for you , you can run the ISO image which you've installed the instance from , then install `xrdp` there and copy the file to your host.

Comment: Thank you, I chose the second option.

Answer (score 1):

Because xrdp considers that file to be a configuration, the other way is to 'purge' the package and reinstall:

```
apt purge xrdp
apt install xrdp
```